# how to use a function in kernel source?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, include, kernel

I need to use the function `void clflush_cache_range(void *vaddr, unsigned int size)` implemented in [arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L132), but I got two problems.

1. How to identify the corresponding header correctly? I naively searched the symbol and it seems that `arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h` is the one.
2. How to include the header `arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h`(if it's the correct one to include)? I tried to `include <asm/cacheflush.h>`, but it didn't work.

> fatal error: asm/cacheflush.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you developing a kernel module or a userspace application?

Comment: Because userspace programs cannot call random kernel functions.  The interface between kernel and userspace is embodied by the defined system calls (documented in section 2 of the manual, among other places), and `clflush_cache_range()` is not one of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Whichever is easier to do. I'm just trying to do a benchmark on cache flush.

Comment: @bl4ck5un YOu have to write Kernel code to use these functions. They wont be available to user space code.

Comment: @bl4ck5un So as follows, you will need a kernel module here.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not very straightforward way but I would look at other files if they are using the function and try to do the same. For e.g. look at `drivers/iommu/intel-iommu.c` on how they use `clflush_cache_range()`

Refer to http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/write-linux-kernel-module/ on how to write kernel code.